# Type error when trying to list all the sub-directories of a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I want to list all the sub-directories of a directory but it throws type error**

```
TRAIN_PATH_ARRAY=['New folder/train/']
TEST_PATH_ARRAY=['New folder/test/']
train_ids = next(os.walk(TRAIN_PATH_ARRAY))[1]
test_ids = next(os.walk(TEST_PATH_ARRAY))[1]
np.random.seed(10)
```

---

Output:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-11-a1a31c46fb70> in <module>
----> 1 train_ids = next(os.walk(TRAIN_PATH_ARRAY))[1]
      2 test_ids = next(os.walk(TEST_PATH_ARRAY))[1]
      3 np.random.seed(10)

~\Anaconda3\lib\os.py in walk(top, topdown, onerror, followlinks)
    334 
    335     """
--> 336     top = fspath(top)
    337     dirs = []
    338     nondirs = []

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

---

Comment: What's the error? Please [edit] to add it, including the traceback. At the moment I would guess you're trying to feed an array or list to [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), which takes a string or path-like object. See [mre] for reference. Speaking of minimal, what does `np.random.seed` have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message rather plainly says, the argument to `os.walk()` should be a `str` (or a `pathlib` path), not a list.

It's not really clear what you hope for the code to actually accomplish. Extracting just the second element out of the first result from `os.walk()` is not correct because it returns a file names relative to the starting directory. But if that's what you are after, maybe try

```py
TRAIN_PATH='New folder/train/'
TEST_PATH='New folder/test/'
train_ids = [os.path.join(TRAIN_PATH, x) for x in next(os.walk(TRAIN_PATH))[1])]
test_ids = [os.path.join(TEST_PATH, x) for x in next(os.walk(TEST_PATH))[1])]
```

If indeed you want to traverse an array, I'm afraid you will need to explain the intention of your code in more detail.